# Running executable file through java hanging

Tags: java, processbuilder

When I run this exe file through the `cmd`it works fine and finish.
But when I run this through `ProcessBuilder` in java, the program get stucked, and the last line that should be printed - is not printed and thats why the java program doesnt finish, i don't know what makes my code to stuck the process.
here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("main.exe", "C:\\Users\\ozdav\\Desktop\\f.FASTA");
    final Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Program terminated!");
}
```

Comment: are you trying to get output from the program or send some input to the program ?

Comment: @gvmani I give the program 1 argument and have to get the output from it. it generates after a file.